# How to write a Google Sheets formula to extra a substring from a URL?

Tags: google-sheets, regexextract

I'm trying to set up a formula to extract data from a URL that is in one of the column B of my Google Sheet.

[image]

I've been tryin use the LEFT formula to extract the data, but the problem is that the string I am trying to extract can be different in size. I couldn't find a formula that can extract between two substrings.

In this example, I want to pull out the Subreddit which occurs in every URL, after the substring: "https://www.reddit.com/r/" and before the ensuing "/". So the output value for C2 would be "AskReddit".

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. It would be helpful if you included the full URL in your question as plain text. This saves volunteers from having to decipher your screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this formula in C2:

```
=index( regexextract(regexreplace(B2:B,"https://www.reddit.com/r/",""),"([^\/]*)"))
```

[image: REGEX]

Comment: Question, why use `[/]` instead of just `\/`? Is it just for readability or is there a difference?

Comment: I changed my mind ... the previous formula could have some problems

Answer (score 0):

This is the old-school approach to this problem.

`=mid(B2,len("https://www.reddit.com/r/")+1,search("/",B2,len("https://www.reddit.com/r/")+1)-len("https://www.reddit.com/r/")-1)`

---

[image: snapshot]